# How can one change the MAC address of USB WiFi Adapter TP-Link Archer T3U Plus on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, usb, network-adapter, mac-address

I use a USB WiFi Adapter ([TP-Link Archer T3U Plus](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B08D72GSMS)) with my Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. How can I change its MAC address?

The [TP-Link Archer T3U Plus manual](https://static.tp-link.com/2020/202009/20200930/1910012742_Archer%20T3U%20Plus_UG_V1.pdf) ([mirror](http://web.archive.org/web/20210929231053/https://static.tp-link.com/2020/202009/20200930/1910012742_Archer%20T3U%20Plus_UG_V1.pdf)) doesn't mention how one can change its MAC address.

---

I have unsuccessfully tried the following:

1. Use [Technitium MAC Address Changer](https://technitium.com/tmac/) (gratis utility to change of the MAC address of network adapters): the USB WiFi Adapter doesn't show up there.
2. [Change the MAC address using Device Manager](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/change-mac-address-windows/):

   [image]
   [image]

   In my case, my USB WiFi Adapter doesn't have the Network Address option:

   [image]
3. [Change the MAC address using Control Panel](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/change-mac-address-windows/): same issue as going via the Device Manager.

Comment: What does the manual tell you? MAC addresses are supposed to be factory set, *many* cards allow setting it, but not all.

Comment: @vonbrand The [TP-Link Archer T3U Plus manual](https://static.tp-link.com/2020/202009/20200930/1910012742_Archer%20T3U%20Plus_UG_V1.pdf) doesn't mention how one can change its MAC address.